# How to make signalEnumerator(for: identifier) call the relevant enumerateChanges method

Tags: swift, macos, fileprovider, fileprovider-extension

In macOS FileProvider extension, when I invoke:

```
manager.signalEnumerator(for: identifier) { error in
    print("Signal completed with error: \(error)")
}
```

where `identifier` is identifier of the relevant folder which contains remote changes, system does NOT call the `enumerateChanges` method on relevant `FileProviderEnumerator`.

On other hand if I invoke

```
manager.signalEnumerator(for: .workingSet) { error in
    print("Signal completed with error: \(error)")
}
```

there the system properly calls the relevant `enumerateChanges` method.

Is there a way to make sure that `enumerateChanges` will be invoked for the provided `itemIdentifier`? Or is there some explanation as to why the system doesn't call the `enumerateChanges` method when I provide folder item identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following note can be found buried in [Using push notifications to signal changes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nonreplicated_file_provider_extension/content_and_change_tracking/tracking_your_file_provider_s_changes/using_push_notifications_to_signal_changes?language=objc)

> When using an NSFileProviderReplicatedExtension, always set the container identifier to NSFileProviderWorkingSetContainerItemIdentifier. The system automatically propagates any working set changes to the user interface, without requiring you to signal individual containers. It ignores any other identifiers.